# URL Masking or cloaking

Tags: dns, masking, cloaking

I am wondering on how to expose a short url that is domain masking ? I am getting these text messages with the same url and I know that this site is masking but I can't figure out what is the actual site. I've already tried using a vpn but its still showing the "masked" site.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Try to make your questions more clear. As it is it is unclear what you are asking about. URL shortening is not designed to mask/cloak destination URL - it is designed to shorten URL. You can use CURL or any other tool with option to **not follow redirects** but display server headers. This way you will know destination URL without sending any requests to the destination URL/server.

Comment: Try to make your questions more clear.

Comment: Well I am wanting to find out the true destination of the URL instead the "masked" site that I see when clicking on the short url. So to be specific, I get the text that includes a short url (www.s8d.co) it then redirects to a site (www.google.com) but I know that wasn't the true destination. I want to figure out the true destination.